# Change look or font for non-printable characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Sometimes I need to open binary files with some text inside. Unfortunately Notepad++ shows most of the binary content as white text on black background and it literally makes my eyes water.

[image]

Is there a way to change the look of these non-printable characters? Or maybe hide them entirely if don't want to see them?

PS: I know that I can open binary files in hex editor but they tend to show ASCII representation in a very narrow column and with annoying large spacing between characters.

Comment: Seems the formatting of control characters [happens on a lower level](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/13580/display-control-characters-as-empty-character-or-as-spacing); you'd need to put in quite a bit of effort to override it, less so to merely hide them.

Comment: Wow, that's a pity. I guess I'll go with regexp replacement then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - in Notepad++ set find by regular expression.

2 - Put this regexp in the search field :

> (?!\r|\n|\t)[\x00-\x1f\x80-\x9f]

3 - replace all with blank.

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked for but I guess that'll do. Thanks! It's a pity that it takes a very long time to process a file less then 1 Mb in size :(

Comment: You're welcome . I left only \r\n but if you want remove also them.